# Dynamic & extendible category names

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm having trouble on something with Google Sheets:
I need category names to be dynamic & extendible between 15-200 values, so it's not quite worth an Apps Script, would be super cool to put the following formula

```
=QUERY(A1:C4, "SELECT COL WHERE" &A1:C1& = &E8&)
```

in such a place as it could reference the dynamically selected dropdown in Cell E8, and return all the values in a dropdown in F8. I've seen videos of dependent dropdowns and 'helper columns' but I think this can be done with query, and putting that formula INSIDE the data validation formula field on that cell. Thoughts? I think the formula is close - it should use E8 to 'select that column, then return all values below it.'

[image]

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RGuwcQ-zAN76fnnWzF4QeFxJrxv2zSsxaT_QMRap2Ls/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

> putting that formula INSIDE the data validation formula field on that cell

That cannot be done with a spreadsheet formula, because currently (January 2023) Google Sheets data validation only supports one type of formula: a reference to a spreadsheet range, using any mix of [absolute and relative](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/1/) row and column references.

What you *can* do is wrap the `query()` formula in `transpose()` and put it in a cell on the same row as the top-level drop-down. The second-level drop-down can then use the **List from a range** option to refer to the cells where the `query()` results are.

In practice, it is usually easier to use an `onEdit(e)` script to manage drop-downs. They let you easily implement multiple levels of dependent drop-downs. Take a look at the [dependentDropDownLists_](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/160451/269219) script for one example.